# What are the differences between event and signal in Qt

Tags: qt, events, signals

It is hard for me to understand the difference between signals and events in Qt, could someone explain?

Comment: I think this is a real question and shouldn't be closed. Here is an answer from Qt Community Documentation: An event in Qt is an object which represents something interesting that happened; the main difference between an event and a signal is that events are targeted to a specific object in our application (which decides what to do with that event), while signals are emitted “in the wild”. From a code point of view, all events are instances of some subclass of QEvent [doc.qt.nokia.com], and all QObject-derived classes can override the QObject::event() virtual method in order to handle event...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Events and Signal/Slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794649/qt-events-and-signal-slots)

Answer (score 17):

An **event** is a **message** encapsulated in a class (`QEvent`) which is processed in an event loop and dispatched to a recipient that can either accept the message or pass it along to others to process. They are usually created in response to external system events like mouse clicks.

**Signals and Slots** are a convenient way for `QObject`s to communicate with one another and are more similar to **callback functions**. In most circumstances, when a "signal" is emitted, any slot function connected to it is called directly. The exception is when signals and slots cross thread boundaries. In this case, the signal will essentially be converted into an event.

Answer (score 14):

Events are something that happened **to** or **within** an object. In general, you would treat them within the object's own class code.

Signals are **emitted** by an object. The object is basically notifying other objects that something happened. Other objects might do something as a result or not, but this is not the emitter's job to deal with it.

Comment: in a strict sens this answer is very good. I can even say that event can be throwed on a object in which it can propagate...this also suppose that there should exist a signal bus (message bus) and object need to register on that bus, apply a filter to catch the signal (message) they want to handle...normally thing should be done like that...but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 6):

My impression of the difference is as follows:

[image]

Say you have a server device, running an infinite loop, listening to some external client Events and reacting to them by executing some code.

(It can be a CPU, listening to interrupts from devices, or Client-side Javascript browser code, litsening for user clicks or Server-side website code, listening for users requesting web-pages or data).

Or it can be your Qt application, running its main loop.

I'll be explaining with the assumption that you're running Qt on Linux with an X-server used for drawing.

I can distinguish 2 main differences, although the second one is somewhat disputable:

1. **Events represent your hardware and are a small finite set. Signals represent your Widgets-layer logic and can be arbitrarily complex and numerous.**

**Events are low-level messages, coming to you from the client. The set of Events is a strictly limited set (~20 different Event types), determined by hardware (e.g. mouse click/doubleclick/press/release, mouse move, keyboard key pressed/released/held etc.), and specified in the protocol of interaction (e.g. X protocol) between application and user.**

E.g. at the time X protocol was created there were no multitouch gestures, there were only mouse and keyboard so X protocol won't understand your gestures and send them to application, it will just interpret them as mouse clicks. Thus, extensions to X protocol are introduced over time.

**X events know nothing about widgets, widgets exist only in Qt.** X events know only about X windows, which are very basic rectangles that your widgets consist of. Your Qt events are just a thin wrapper around X events/Windows events/Mac events, providing a compatibility layer between different Operating Systems native events for convenience of Widget-level logic layer authors.

Widget-level logic deals with Signals, cause they include the Widget-level meaning of your actions. Moreover, **one Signal can be fired due to different events, e.g. either mouse click on "Save" menu button or a keyboard shortcut such as Ctrl-S**.

2. Abstractly speaking (this is not exactly about Qt!), Events are asynchronous in their nature, while Signals (or hooks in other terms) are synchronous.

Say, you have a function foo(), that can fire Signal OR emit Event.
If it fires signal, **Signal is executed in the same thread of code as the function, which caused it, right after the function**.

On the other hand, if it emits Event, **Event is sent to the main loop and it depends on the main loop, when it delivers that event to the receiving side and what happens next.**

Thus 2 consecutive events may even get delivered in reversed order, while 2 consecutively fired signals remain consecutive.

Though, terminology is not strict. "Singals" in Unix as a means of Interprocess Communication should be better called Events, cause they are asynchronous: you call a signal in one process and never know, when the event loop is going to switch to the receiving process and execute the signal handler.

*P.S. Please forgive me, if some of my examples are not absolutely correct in terms of letter. They are still good in terms of spirit.*

Comment: This answer is amazing.

Answer (score 4):

An event is passed directly to an event handler method of a class. They are available for you to overload in your subclasses and choose how to handle the event differently. Events also pass up the chain from child to parent until someone handles it or it falls off the end.

Signals on the other hand are openly emitted and any other entity can opt to connect and listen to them. They pass through the event loops and are processed in a queue (they can also be handled directly if they are in the same thread).