# Can eventFilter react to signals on Qt

Tags: qt

I am emiting a signal from mainwindow to my editor class where my event filter is placed is there any way for enent filter react to Signals

**mainwindow:**

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(MidiMessage(QString)),Editor, 
SLOT(getMsgfromUi(QString)));

emit  MidiMessage(QString::number(message->getStatus()));
```

**my editor class:**

```
bool Editor::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
  {
    if (e->type()==??signal
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between event and signal in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323888/what-are-the-differences-between-event-and-signal-in-qt)

Comment: another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794649/qt-events-and-signal-slots

Comment: Signals and events are 2 different things.

Comment: No, you can't since a signal isn't an event. You *can* emit a signal from an event handler if you wish, but you can't compare them. `eventFilter()` in your example has nothing to do with any singal; it just filters out events and executes the desired commands.