# Is there a way to debug Qt slot calls queued for the object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

An object lives in a thread and have some slots, that are called with

```
Qt::QueuedConnection
```

or

```
Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection
```

Is there a way to know how many `slot calls` are in the queue? Or even know `number of each slot calls` in the that `queue`?

Comment: I would simply use debug output (either `qDebug()` or `printf`) in slots to print out each call, than analyze the log.

Comment: Do you mean to get the number of queued slot call events in the event queue at the moment? Why would you need to know that?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Right now this sounds a bit [XY](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @vahancho this thread is used for sound streaming/receiving, so lots of qDebug/printf would screw the timing up for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some best practices for debugging Qt signals and slots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938550/what-are-some-best-practices-for-debugging-qt-signals-and-slots)

Comment: @Mike yes them. Thread start to consume lots of CPU time at some point and never comes back to normal (besides thread recreation). Unfortunately we can't reproduce the issue on any but one PC and even there it takes days to happen. So I need to debug as much information at that time as possible. One of that is an assumption that the object gets flooded with some slot calls. If it's true we can inspect the reason of the flood.

Comment: @G.M. I try to inspect if thread has problems with some slot called too many times. Not the statistics from the very program start, but current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit offtopic, but next pattern may help you (when you need only one slot call per several operations). For example, when you have a lot of unpredictable data changes and you need to update a view.

```
class SlotProxy : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

signals:
  void triggered();

public:
  explicit SlotProxy( QObject *parent = nullptr );
  void trigger();

private:
  void onTimeout();

private:
  QPointer<QTimer> _timer;
};

SlotProxy::SlotProxy( QObject *parent = nullptr )
  : _timer{ new QTimer{ this } }
{
  _timer->setInterval( 0 );
  _timer->setSingleShot( true );
  connect( _timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SlotProxy::onTimeout );
}

void SlotProxy::trigger()
{
  _timer->start( 0 ); // May be not zero;
}

void SlotProxy::onTimeout()
{
  emit triggered();
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyForm : public QWidget
{
/*...*/
void updateGui();
};

class Worker : public QObject
{
/*...*/
signals:
  void updateRequest();

public:
  explicit Worker( QObject *parent = nullptr );

private:
  void heavyTask();

private:
  SlotProxy _proxy;
};

Worker::Worker( QObject *parent )
  : QObject{ parent }
{
  connect( _proxy, &SlotProxy::triggered, this, &Worker::updateRequest );
}

void Worker::heavyTask()
{
  for ( auto i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
  {
    /*...*/
    _proxy.trigger();
  }
}

MyForm form;
Worker worker;

QObject::connect( &worker, &Worker::updateRequest, &form, &MyForm::updateGui );
worker.heavyTask();
// here you will have only 1 slot MyForm::updateGui in queue
```

Subject to improve. You may call `_timer->start( 100 );` with non-zero timeout for better latency, but you need to somehow force emitting a signal periodically. It will do a code a bit more complex, please write a comment if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10887157/1329652) for details. You need to monitor (via a filter) the `QMetaCallEvent` events.