# Deleting object that inherits from QWidget, WA_DeleteOnClose segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qwidget

I'm using an object the inherits QWidget, and in order to know when it is closed, I've used `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)`, and connected

```
connect(myObj,SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)),this,SLOT(handleFinish()));
```

However, when the object is being deleted, I get `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`, and when I look at the address of the pointer, it is one of the data members of myObj, which is really not a pointer.

I allocate myObj dynamically, so it is supposed to be on the heap - `myObj = new myObj();`
The error comes at the end of myObj destructor, and I've checked that this is the first time the destructor is called (after looking at [When setting the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute on a Qt MainWindow, the program crashes when deleting the ui pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153155/when-setting-the-wa-deleteonclose-attribute-on-a-qt-mainwindow-the-program-cras)).

Any suggestions for dealing with it?

Comment: Does the `handleFinish()` slot get invoked? You are corrupting your memory. I think that this question is unanswerable unless you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try isolating the problem by temporarily removing statements from the destructor and/or remove member data (that gets destructed when the object is destroyed), And observe the statement/member variable that causes the crash not to occur when it is commented out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you receive the `destroyed` signal, the object is only a `QObject` - not a `QWidget` and definitely not of any derived type. You can only access the members and methods provided via `QObject`, not via any other type.

It seems that you wish to be notified when a widget is about to close: for that, install an event filter that intercepts `QEvent::close` on the widget. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336771/1329652) and [a discussion of why a `closeEvent` cannot be generally handled via a slot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172340/1329652).

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I needed.