# How Qt Handle Events and Signal in Same EventLoop

Tags: qt, qevent, qeventloop

I couldn't understand how qt handle events (e.g timer event, socket event etc.) and signals in same event loop.As I understand,timer and socket events are handled via select system call(in Unix like OS).

How an event loop handle signals while sleeping because of select system call.

Comment: What a sleeping you are talking about? The event loop in the context of which you are located, will not sleep until you yourself in your code call a long blocking operation. Read this nice answer about events and signals it Qt https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794944/4149835

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read that answer but I couldn't understand that how it handle timer events , socket events and signals with same select system call. It can handle socket events and timers event using file descriptors and select's timeout parameter. But how a Qt signal notify that select call.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt, signals are used to call slots. When you emit a signal, there are, roughly speaking, only 2 options for calling the corresponding slot:

1. Direct slot call. This can be thought of as replacing a line with a signal emitting by a line with just a slot call. An event loop is not used to process this signal itself.
2. Delayed slot call. In this case, the signal will be converted to an event, and the event will be posted to the receiver event loop (*the event enqueues in the event loop of the thread the receiver object is living in*). From now on, for the processing receiver event loop, it makes no difference whether it was a signal or an event. The event will be picked up by the event loop and will cause the slot invocation sometime later.

From Qt doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals

> When a signal is emitted, the slots connected to it are usually
>   executed **immediately, just like a normal function call. When this
>   happens, the signals and slots mechanism is totally independent of any
>   GUI event loop**. Execution of the code following the emit statement
>   will occur once all slots have returned. The situation is slightly
>   different when using **queued connections**; in such a case, the code
>   following the emit keyword will continue immediately, and the slots
>   will be **executed later**.

As for understanding an event loop, an event loop is just a loop which process one event from an event queue on each iteration.
In short, this can be represented as follows:

```
QQueue<QEvent> eventQueue; // Events (and pending slot calls as well) are added to this queue
...

// How an event loop works (schematically):
while(event = eventQueue.dequeue())
{
    do_what_the_event_wants_or_ignore_it(event);
}
```

Read also https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects

Comment: I wonder that How it multiplex io event,timer event and signal event via only one select system call.So how It handle signal event while main event loop waiting for IO event. As I understand from qeventdispatcher_unix.cpp file,it wakes main event loop up via eventfd system call and handle signal events

Comment: @overlord then you need to provide the part of code where you think the events are combined

Comment: @overlord please note that the title of your question is "How Qt Handle Events and Signal in Same EventLoop"