# Should I use Qt Signal or Event?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm using PySide2 and not clearly about *Signal* and *Event*

If we have two people are doing two View.

**Person A** is doing **ListView**

**Person B** is doing **ParameterView**

while **ListItem** be selected, update **ParameterView**

How should I Connect them? use *Signal* or *Event*?

Maybe I would have another **View**, it needs to be update also, while **ListItem** *selectChanged*

---

*Signal*

```
class ListView(QListView):
    # do something

class ParameterView(QWidget):
    def update(self):
        # do something

list_view = ListView()
parameter_view = ParameterView()
list_view.selectChanged.connect(parameter_view.update)
```

*Event*

```
class ListView(QListView):
    def selectChanged(self):
        QApplication.sendEvent(self, SelectChangedEvent)

class SelectChangedEvent(QEvent):
    # initialize ...

class ParameterView(QWidget):
    def update(self):
        # do something

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == SelectChangedEvent:
            self.update()
```

[image]

Comment: if you are using thread, signal is a good choice, signals can emit in threads and change view widgets

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read a comparison between signals and events and decide what is right for you
https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/start/signals-slots-events/
I believe you better use single and slots to solve this problem but this is your choice

Hope this helped you decide, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are valid since they use the same mechanism to transmit the information but the great difference is that if you want to send a QEvent then you must access the object in that space and instead with the Qt signals you should not know the object in that space but only in the connection.

My recommendation is that signals should be used to decouple classes. I recommend you read:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html
- [Qt events and signal/slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794649/qt-events-and-signal-slots)