# enable/disable widget using mousePressEvent/mouseReleaseEvent

Tags: qt

I have a set of widgets to control a parameter in five similar places (or channels).

[image]

Now I can enable/disable each of these widgets using a pushbuttons, as follows.

```
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnOne, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentOne, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnTwo, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentTwo, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnThree, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentThree, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnFour, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentFour, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
connect(ui->pushButton_currOnFive, &QPushButton::clicked, ui->widget_currentFive, &CurrentButtonOne::setEnabled);
```

Can I use `mousePressEvent/mouseReleaseEvent` instead of using `&QPushButton::clicked` in the above scenario?
It will be very helpful if you could show me an example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Difference between signals (`QPushButton::clicked`) and events (`mousePressEvent`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794649/qt-events-and-signal-slots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code to get you started.

*mybutton.h:*

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    explicit MyButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override;
    
private:
    bool isPressed = false;
    
signals:
    void myButtonPressed();
};
```

*mybutton.cpp:*

```
#include "mybutton.h"

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    
}

void MyButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    isPressed = true;
    emit myButtonPressed();
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(e);
}

void MyButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    isPressed = false;
    QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}
```

I'm not sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this idea should meet your needs.

You create a class, which inherits from `QPushButton` (or `QAbstractButton`) and override its `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. If you want some other widgets to react on this events, you emit signal and connect other widgets to that signal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Now I got the basic idea of using QEvents. Just to add, my requirement to enable/disable the `QWidget` using mousePress/Rlease events (toggle Qwidget with mouse events). In this case what do you recommend?